# Not entirely sure where am I supposed to write my CSS in a Vue SPA

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

Up until now, I've always used a single CSS file when creating multiple page applications which would store all my CSS rules.

Now that I'm using Vue.js and components, I am not sure where to write my CSS.

I could write the CSS in the `<style></style>` tags of a component but to me this only makes sense if the CSS is only used for this specific component. This leaves me wondering where should I write CSS which I would like to be applied globally to everything.

Imagine I have some CSS which I want to be applied to everything like this snippet:

```
*, *:after, *:before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Where would I write it?

Comment: Well, you could use whatever works best for you. For example you could add all css that is components-specific into component's <style></style> part while creating a file with global styles and loading it in app's main component with `import path/.../styles.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a better solution I can offer two suggestions:

#### 1. In App.vue file

**If it's just a small amount of code, put it in your App.vue file**

*As you said:*

> "I could write the CSS in the  tags of a component but to me this only makes sense if the CSS is only used for this specific component."

If you put CSS in the in the `<style></style>`in any .vue files that's part of your project it's going to be global.

`<style></style>` get's applied to the whole project unless you add *scoped* to the tag.

```
<style scoped>
    body {
        background: green; /* This won't effected your main <body> tag unless you actually have a `<body>` inside the `<template>` of that file */
    }
</style>
```

---

#### 2. Import a separate file containing only CSS (updated and easier)

**From @Fabjan in the comments.**
Just import the `.css` file in your `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './assets/lib/css/reset.css' // my own reset file
import './assets/lib/css/myMain.css' // global stylesheet
```

Make sure to put it before your run your app. `new Vue({})`

---

#### (3. My previous answer:)

You can create a styles.vue and add all your global styles there inside `<styles></styles>` without *scoped*. (this worked for me)

Then inside your main.js file you write:

```
import GlobalStyles from "./assets/lib/css/styles.vue"

Vue.use(GlobalStyles)
```

Make sure your styles.vue contains at least on tag inside  for it to import properly.

```
<template>
    <div class="empty">

    </div>
</template>

<style>
    body {
        background: red;
        /* The rest of your Global CSS code */
}
</style>
```

This feels really tacky but it worked for me now.

Hope it helps and I'd love some feedback or comments if people have better solutions.

Comment: I found that creating a .vue component when importing wasn't necessary. So instead of using `import Name from './path.vue'` and then calling `Vue.use(Name)` it's possible to just import the .css file directly with `import './path.css'`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to configure global scss with my project that using Nuxt.

1. Assume that you already have `node sass` and `sass-loader` installed.
2. In `nuxt.config.js` file add your SCSS path from `static` or `assets` folder

   css: [
       '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
   ]

Bonus: if you don't like this way maybe you can get a try [nuxt-sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/anteriovieira/nuxt-sass-resources-loader)